# Palm down action

Tags: iphone, ipad

this may sound silly, but is there a way to find palm down action on a iphone or ipad.

i am making a simple drawing app, and want to interpret a palm down on the screen action to put a palm imprint/image in the UIView.

so, i should be able to analyse if the touch event is a palm or not right ? how do i go about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your best bet would be to use the [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) after creating a custom gesture recognizer. (See the "Creating Custom Gesture Recognizers" section within [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html).)

However, the problem will be the fact that you're going to have a large area of contact that isn't necessarily constant and pretty much all the standard code is designed to pick up discrete touches on the display.

Comment: I didn't try it, but I guess palm down may be interpreted as an indeterministic multi-touch event.

Comment: @Costique - Yes, I suspect something along those lines will be the case. :-(

Comment: thanks, will have to check it out. but i guess @costique may be right. but, is there a way i can determine the approximate outline by taking the points of contact and plotting it ?